How to group / ungroup or expand node groups in gephi 0.10
In gephi 0.10, how to group nodes / ungroup nodes / expand node groups  ?
ie: how to do with gephi 0.10 (and not 0.7) the same as what happens between in the first 25s of the introduction video available at https://gephi.org/videos/ [1].
There is no group or ungroup menu in 0.10, and I couldn't find a layout or a plugin to have this option available.
[1] also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFBkAO1MjnU

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can't.
This feature has been removed in 0.9.0: https://github.com/gephi/gephi/releases/tag/v0.9.0

Remove ClusteringAPI from codebase. It needs a complete rewrite.


does anyone know when this will be added back?
